# Is there a way to fetch data from api call once in retrofit?

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit, retrofit2, android-networking

I have a Fragment in a navigation drawer, and in the onCreate method there's a retrofit api call to fetch some data from a server.

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient(false).create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<MoviesWrapper> call = apiService.getMovies("upcoming", PreferencesHelper.getLanguage(context), "US");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MoviesWrapper>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MoviesWrapper> call, Response<MoviesWrapper> response) {
            MoviesWrapper moviesWrapper = response.body();
            assert moviesWrapper != null;
            final HomeAdapter moviesAdapter = new HomeAdapter(getContext(), moviesWrapper.getMovies(), null, true);
            moviesRv.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);
            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MoviesWrapper> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(Constants.STRINGS.FAILURE, t.toString());
        }
    });
```

My problem is every time I go in the fragment, retrofit fetches the data from the server. Is there a way to cache the data in retrofit and not make the api call every time?

Comment: You can set the cache object in OkHttpClient and set the OkHttpClient object with the retrofit. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-activate-response-caching-etag-last-modified

Answer (score 0):

You can call **API** in activity and pass response to fragment, it'll prevent recursive call every time for fragment.

You can share some code, i'll provide detailed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit cannot cache fetched data itself. The best way is to fetch them, then save in local database by using e.g. Room Persistence Library or Realm.

And strategy should by like this:

1. Check if data in local database exists.
2. If not fetch them and save in local database
3. Load data from local database and display on screen

Also you should create classes which be responsible for this function. And implement callback/listener which will provide data from these classes to your fragment. Because implementing API calls in Activity or Fragment is bad choice. It create a huge mess in development.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a very efficient solution, because every time the user opens the app I'm making the api call (data might have changed therefore I need to fetch the new data from the api call). Your solution would mean I do all this operation for every single Api Call and every time the user opens the app.

Comment: You can add another API call which will returns change timestamp and compare this value with timestamp in local database. Then fetch new data only if fetched timestamp is before local. This solution protects you against no network access. Because you always have some data in local database to display, even if network is unavailable

Comment: That would be my solution but unfortunately I am using the TMDb api which I can't control. My thought is to create a singleton class that holds the api response. So I would follow the same process you suggested but use that in a singleton class. Would that affect the performance a lot?

Comment: Or add `lastFetchTime` as parameter to current API call. And add some logic on server. E.g. if param is null return all data else if there weren't any changes return empty list

Comment: You see the Android system can kill your application at any given time. When it does all your static variables go away too. The funky thing is though, the application can be killed, and you won’t restart from your MAIN LAUNCHER activity. If the user did not specifically kill the app, the app stays in the recently used apps and the user can restart it from the activity it was suspended on. Then if you try to use data from singleton you will throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: Alright I understand that. But I'm really skeptical about using Room or Realm, the app is pretty big and it will end up taking so much space.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not being changed from an API then you can store the data into SharedPreferences or local database or you can serialize the data into ObjectSerializer(ByteArrayInputStream/ByteArrayOutputStream. If data is being changed then you can implement Firebase push notification as the push will come then can hit that API and you will get that data. Hope it'll give you an idea what you can use among all of these according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add this two lines to build.gradle(app)**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

**2. create the following structure**

```
->API
        ->ApiClient
        ->ApiInterface      
->database
        ->dbHelper
        ->itemDB
->models
        ->IitemResult
        ->restItems
```

**3. ApiCleint.java**

```
package test.com.testapp.API;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class APIClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "TEST_URL";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient()
    {
        if (retrofit == null)
        {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;

    }
}
```

**4. ApiInterface.java**

```
package test.com.testapp.API;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import test.com.testapp.models.IItemResult;

public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("String id")
    Call<IItemResult> getItems();   

}
```

**5. dbHelper.java**

```
package test.com.testapp.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import test.com.testapp.models.restItems;

public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DsTest";

    public dbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(ItemDB.CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ItemDB.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public long InsertItem(restItems restItem){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ItemDB.COLUMN_BRAND_DEC, restItem.getBrandDesc());
        values.put(ItemDB.COLUMN_MRP, restItem.getmRP());
        values.put(ItemDB.COLUMN_VAT_RATE, restItem.getVatRate());

        long id = db.insert(ItemDB.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        db.close();

        return id;
    }

    public List<restItems> getItemList(){

        List<restItems> restItems =new ArrayList<>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + ItemDB.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " +
                ItemDB.COLUMN_ID + " DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                restItems item = new restItems();
                //   item.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.COLUMN_ID)));
                item.setBrandDesc(cursor.getColumnName(1));
                item.setmRP(cursor.getColumnName(2));
                item.setVatRate(cursor.getColumnName(3));

                restItems.add(item);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        db.close();

        return restItems;
    }
}
```

**6. ItemDb.java**

```
package test.com.testapp.database;

public class ItemDB {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "items";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_BRAND_DEC = "brand_dec";
    public static final String COLUMN_MRP = "mrp";
    public static final String COLUMN_VAT_RATE = "vat_rate";

    private String Id;
    private String Brand_Desc;
    private String Mrp;
    private String Vat_rate;

    public ItemDB(String id, String brand_Desc, String mrp, String vat_rate) {
        Id = id;
        Brand_Desc = brand_Desc;
        Mrp = mrp;
        Vat_rate = vat_rate;
    }

    public ItemDB() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getBrand_Desc() {
        return Brand_Desc;
    }

    public void setBrand_Desc(String brand_Desc) {
        Brand_Desc = brand_Desc;
    }

    public String getMrp() {
        return Mrp;
    }

    public void setMrp(String mrp) {
        Mrp = mrp;
    }

    public String getVat_rate() {
        return Vat_rate;
    }

    public void setVat_rate(String vat_rate) {
        Vat_rate = vat_rate;
    }

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT,"
            + COLUMN_BRAND_DEC + "TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_MRP + "TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_VAT_RATE + "TEXT"
                    + ")";
}
```

**7. restItems.java**

```
package test.com.testapp.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class restItems {

    @SerializedName("Brand")
    private String brand;
    @SerializedName("MRP")
    private String mrp;
    @SerializedName("VAT")
    private String vat;

    public restItems(String brand, String mrp, String vat) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.mrp = mrp;
        this.vat = vat;
    }

    public restItems() {
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getMrp() {
        return mrp;
    }

    public void setMrp(String mrp) {
        this.mrp = mrp;
    }

    public String getVat() {
        return vat;
    }

    public void setVat(String vat) {
        this.vat = vat;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "restItems{" +
                "brand='" + brand + '\'' +
                ", mrp='" + mrp + '\'' +
                ", vat='" + vat + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**8. IItemResult .java**

```
package test.com.testapp.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class IItemResult {
    @SerializedName("iItemResult")
    private List<restItems>iItemResult = null;

    public IItemResult(List<restItems> iItemResult) {
        this.iItemResult = iItemResult;
    }

    public void setiItemResult(List<restItems> iItemResult) {
        this.iItemResult = iItemResult;
    }

    public List<restItems> getiItemResult() {
        return iItemResult;
    }
}
```

**9. MainActivity.java**

```
package test.com.testapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import test.com.testapp.API.APIClient;
import test.com.testapp.API.ApiInterface;
import test.com.testapp.database.dbHelper;
import test.com.testapp.models.IItemResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button getData;
    private ProgressBar bar;
    private dbHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGet);
        bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pBar);

        getData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new insertData().execute("");
            }
        });

    }

    private class insertData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            ApiInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

            db = new dbHelper(getApplicationContext());

            Call<IItemResult>resultCall = apiInterface.getItems();
            resultCall.enqueue(new Callback<IItemResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<IItemResult> call, Response<IItemResult> response) {
                    System.out.println("MAIN_ACTIVITY"  + response.body().getiItemResult().size());
                    System.out.println(response.body().getiItemResult().get(1));

                    for (int i=0; i<response.body().getiItemResult().size(); i++)
                    {
                        db.InsertItem(response.body().getiItemResult().get(i));
                    }

                    System.out.println("DB_RESULT: " + db.getItemList());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<IItemResult> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```